# How to run "grunt serve" as case sensitive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs

We are building an app with angularjs.
Because of "reasons" some files in index.html are misspelled, for example: patientRequests.js -> PatientRequests.js.

In dev we use "grunt serve" and everything works.
When deploying to tomcat case sensitivity comes into play and those mistakes cause crashes.

Is there a way to make "grunt serve" case sentive? It would help to find these when they are made.

Comment: Is the case sensitive problem related to **grunt** or is it a **Windows** / **Unix** file system problem?

Comment: Why do you have your individual .js files included in index.html? why not use grunt by telling it where you keep your .js file and have it build a single application.js file? that way you don't have to keep track of anything

Comment: I'm sure it's just a windows/linux thing, but since I can't change that I have to work in windows, changing grunt is probably the simplest solution

Comment: kajo, we do that too, but for some wierd dev things we sometimes add them by hand as well

Comment: How about normalizing your filenames if you don't want to just build a single js file (likely a better option)? Following a naming convention is a Good Idea anyway-don't let the smell linger.

Comment: Yes, we need to have the names correct. Grunt won't fix that, only warn us of errors while still in dev

Comment: This happens because we don't use build cycle in dev mode and the script tag allows the case-insensitive js also

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom filter function on the task in question to compare the filename to it's lowercase version, then log a warning:

```
filter: function(filepath) 
  {
  if(RegExp(filepath.toLowerCase()).test(filepath))
    {
    grunt.log.error(filepath + " case does not match " + filepath.toLowerCase() );
    return false;
    }
  else
    {
    return true ;
    }
  }
```

> The filter property can help you target files with a greater level of detail. Simply use a valid [fs.Stats](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats) method name.
>
> Or create your own filter function and return true or false whether the file should be matched.

**References**

- [grunt API: grunt.log](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.log)
- [grunt Documentation- Configuring tasks: Custom Filter Function](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#custom-filter-function)
- [nodeJS API: Class: fs.Stats](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats)

Comment: Hey, thks for the suggestion. I don't really have time to implement this in the next few days, but i'll definitely check it out.